# Read only header lines from a log file

Tags: .net

At my workplace, we have log files which can grow up to Gigabytes in size, if all parameters are set. The format of these files are:

```
[HEADER ROW 1]
  XML LINE 1
  XML LINE 2
  . . .
  XML LINE x
[HEADER ROW 2]
  XML LINE 1
  XML LINE 2
  . . .
  XML LINE y
.  .  .
[HEADER ROW n]
  XML LINE 1
  XML LINE 2
  . . .
  XML LINE z
```

The header row has useful information, such as the datetime stamp of the message, and its general type. Parsing the entire file would take a long time, so ideally I would like to do an initial pass through the log file, ignoring all lines except ones which start with "[". However, I am unexperienced with the various .NET IO classes. Could someone please recommend an efficient way to do this?

Oh, and I forgot - this has got to work with a file which is currently open for writing in another process. No big ask :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think using [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the right way to do. You can even read the file asynchronously!

You could also make a program that reads lines from Console and writes the right ones. Then you could use a command line like this:

```
C:\type LOGFILE | PROGRAM
```

Alternatively, you can use a grep-like program, like [WinGrep](http://www.wingrep.com/).